# unable to connect to sftp server using php

Tags: php

I want to connect to sftp server.
Code I am using is ..

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('hostip');
if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password')) {
throw new Exception('Unable to connect.'); }
if (!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection)) {
throw new Exception('Unable to create SFTP connection.'); }
```

But showing error as_

```
This page isn’t working. currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500
```

Main Purpose of doing so is -
I want to access file `filename.txt` from `sample.php`

Path is_ `/var/data/hostdata/myadmin/public_html/new1/new2/sample.php`

& want to access

```
/var/data/vmail/updates.com/admin/curDir/filename.txt
```

But `PHP` is mapped till `/var/data/hostdata/myadmin/public_html`

So unable to get proper path.
That's the reason I want to create new sftp connection

Comment: `500` is server error. First one, you can using `winscp` or any app like that to check if the SFTP server still working or died.

Comment: Is that the whole code? HTTP ERROR 500 means an error occurred on the server and it's likely not even running the code you're showing. Check the server logs for more info.

Comment: SFTP server is working.  I am currently implementing new programs and codes on it.  & they are working fine.

Comment: You could use this and thank me later: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib PHP Sec Lib make SFTP from PHP easy

Comment: Should `if (!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection)) {` be `if ($sftp != ssh2_sftp($connection)) {`?

Comment: why you sould do this ? you can only read the file dirctly with fopen

Answer (score 0):

At first try connection via ssh2(command prompt),
after that check your iptables and firewalld,
an again check your log files from client and server side,
if you come out of the internet behind a firewall then check roles.